# Select all rows with 2 most recent dates by ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to select all rows with the 2 most recent dates by each ID. Max and Max-1 dates and number of rows for each ID may differ for ID's.

Example Data:

```
data = {'id':  np.repeat((['a','b','c']), 6),
        'date': ['2020-12-07', '2020-12-07','2020-12-05','2020-12-05','2020-12-04','2020-12-04',
                 '2021-12-07', '2021-12-07','2021-09-05','2021-09-05','2021-05-04','2021-05-04',
                 '2021-09-05', '2021-09-05','2021-02-05','2021-02-05','2020-12-04','2020-12-04'],
        'value1': np.repeat(([10,20,30]), 6),
        'value2': np.repeat(([1000,2000,3000]), 6)
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Desired output:

```
   id   date    value1  value2
0   a   2020-12-07  10  1000
1   a   2020-12-07  10  1000
2   a   2020-12-05  10  1000
3   a   2020-12-05  10  1000
4   b   2021-12-07  20  2000
5   b   2021-12-07  20  2000
6   b   2021-09-05  20  2000
7   b   2021-09-05  20  2000
8   c   2021-09-05  30  3000
9   c   2021-09-05  30  3000
10  c   2021-02-05  30  3000
11  c   2021-02-05  30  3000
```

I've read that `.nlargest()` can pull the the last two dates, but I'm having trouble finding a way to apply it to my use case and maintain the other values in my df.

Comment: Are the `Max` and `Max-1` depend on the `ID` or are they the same across the ID?

Comment: Max and Max-1 depend on the ID. That is to say each ID may have a unique Max and Max-1. Some will certainly share, but there is not a reliable pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `groupby().nth`:

```
df[df['date']>=df.groupby("id")["date"].transform('nth', n=2)]
```

Output:

```
   id        date  value1  value2
0   a  2020-12-07      10    1000
1   a  2020-12-07      10    1000
2   a  2020-12-05      10    1000
3   a  2020-12-05      10    1000
6   b  2021-12-07      20    2000
7   b  2021-12-07      20    2000
8   b  2021-09-05      20    2000
9   b  2021-09-05      20    2000
12  c  2021-09-05      30    3000
13  c  2021-09-05      30    3000
14  c  2021-02-05      30    3000
15  c  2021-02-05      30    3000
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try with a "dense" ranking:

```
>>> df[df.groupby("id")["date"].transform(pd.Series.rank, ascending=False, method="dense")<=2]

   id       date  value1  value2
0   a 2020-12-07      10    1000
1   a 2020-12-07      10    1000
2   a 2020-12-05      10    1000
3   a 2020-12-05      10    1000
6   b 2021-12-07      20    2000
7   b 2021-12-07      20    2000
8   b 2021-09-05      20    2000
9   b 2021-09-05      20    2000
12  c 2021-09-05      30    3000
13  c 2021-09-05      30    3000
14  c 2021-02-05      30    3000
15  c 2021-02-05      30    3000
```